# MAC address randomly changes when bringing interface up

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

Every time I start my network interface, I get a different MAC address! If I try to force the MAC address value using

`ifconfig usb0 hw ether AA:BB:DD..:FF`

it will be again different after issuing

`ifconfig usb0 up`

What make this MAC address change? How can I stop this to happen and stick to HW burned MAC address?

I am using a panda board (omap4/armv7) on a angtrom distribution. The inteface is a smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet.

Thanks,
Fabrice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with the smsc95xx driver.

[[PATCH] smsc95xx: generate random MAC address once, not every ifup](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/70809/)

There is also something in the work to get a 'repeatable' MAC generation going, but it didn't get much uptake:

[Beagleboard xM smsc95xx MAC address from die id](http://groups.google.com/group/beagleboard/browse_thread/thread/92d41bb344f8939b)

**Edit** just searching for [smsc95xx mac address](http://tinyurl.com/3d6fonj) gives a ton of competing patches, with some more explanations (the smc hub+NIC frequently doesn't have an EEPROM, so also no MAC)

Comment: Thanks! After reading the patch description I have an extra question: If I use the patch, I still get to have a random MAC addr each time I reboot, but my IT team configured their DHCP server to provide me with an IP based on a stable MAC address... It seams MAC addresses are set random in many systems now that does not fit with what I learned about them ...in the 90's... How do I get a fixed IP with a random MAC?

Comment: @Fafaman: If you follow the search link  you'll find patches that allow setting a fixed MAC as part of the module parameters (and possibly on the fly?) - within the first few hits as well :). One patch even hardcodes a MAC address, if I saw correctly in the quick glances

Answer (score 0):

MAC addresses are typically coded in the chipset, but mutable.

It might be that your distro is randomising it for security reasons.

Comment: Or just, that the USB device doesn't support it.